# How to change the key of the form passed to a template using a class based view

Tags: python, django, forms, inheritance

I have a template that references a form like {{ registeredteamform.team_name }}, but Django's generic class based views pass forms using the key 'form'.  Rather than changing the form name in my template (I'm dealing with a multi-form situation) I'd like to change they *key* of the form passed to the template.

I tried extending the `render_to_response` method like so

```
def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        response_kwargs['registeredteamform'] = context['form']
        return super().render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs)
```

but this raises the error `render_to_response() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.  So, how can I change the form key and is render_to_response the appropriate place to do this?  (I'm subclassing the `CreateView`),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is because of the way you are using super. The `self` goes in the `super()` for Python 2.7, and you don't need to pass the self at all for Python 3.

[Python 2.7:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)

`return super(MyClassView, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)`

[Python 3:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

`return super().render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)`

If you dig into the `CreateView` you will see that it is in the `get()` that form actually gets assigned to the `form` key.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handles GET requests and instantiates a blank version of the form.
    """
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

You could add in the key the way you are now, but the `form` key will still be getting assigned too.

I might suggest overriding the `get()`.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(registeredteamform =form))
```

Comment: Actually, OP appears to be using Python 3, where `super()` with no arguments is correct. But you are right that `self` should not be used in the arguments to `render_to_response`.